# How do I stay on the same tab in a webpage after submitting a form using Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

When I refresh the page/submit a form for my django app, it always goes to the first tab instead of redirecting to the tab the user was currently on. Is there any simple fix for this because I haven't found any answers online

Comment: when you change tab, is there any change in the URL? share screenshots of browser when you are on home tag and when you are on another tab.

Comment: There is no change in the URL & all the tabs are in the same HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can save tab selection to [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and use it on page load. If you use Bootstrap (and jQuery) and follow their [basic guidelines](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#javascript-behavior), then code like this should do the job:

```
// Save last active tab to sessionStorage
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    try {
        sessionStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

... and this to go to last active tab on page load:

```
// Get last active tab from sesssionStorage and go there
var lastTab = sessionStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if (lastTab) {
    $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

One thing you should be careful about when using this code is that you use unique tab ids.

Include this in a Django template, where you have these navigational tabs:

```
{% block extrahead %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready( function() {

        // Save last active tab to sessionStorage
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
            try {
                sessionStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        // Get last active tab from sesssionStorage and go there
        var lastTab = sessionStorage.getItem('lastTab');
        if (lastTab) {
            $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
        }

    )};

</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This isn't Django specific. It's js/jquery. Include it in Django template like you would any other page specific js/jQuery code.

Comment: So do I make another js file? I'm confused as to where this code would even go

Comment: @jh122, I've added an example how to add this to template.